# MVC4 project - cannot have dot in parameter value?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 project, and I am trying to get it working on URLs like /QRCode/address/amount. Here's how it is declared:

Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "QRCode",
    url: "QRCode/{address}/{amount}",
    defaults: new { controller = "QRCode", action = "Index" }
);
```

Controller:

```
public class QRCodeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string address, double amount)
    {
         ...
```

The problem is:

When URL is: `QRCode/address1/33`, all works fine, but if there is a dot in second parameter, such as: `QRCode/address1/33.33`, I am getting a "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found".

Re-declaring second parameter a string yields same result.

Using %2E in lieu of a dot yields same result

Anybody knows what is going on here? I know it worked fine in MVC3

Comment: "dots" usually trigger IIS to try and map the file to a MIME type, then to a handler. So IIS is probably looking for a .33 handler, which of course doesn't exist. Is your web.config configured to run all requests through the pipeline?

Comment: I would check handler mappings..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if this is on IIS 7, then add this to your config file and it should work fine:

```
<system.web>
     <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: I tested, and it does indeed do the trick. Apparently, what changed was not MVC version, but rather runtime. My httpRuntime tag had targetFramework="4.5", this is what caused the issue. relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes... See comments, the handler mapping was a problem.

I changed URL from QRCode/address1/33.33 to QRCode/address1/33.33/ and mapping worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option: don't map the amount but pass it as a URL parameter with name:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "QRCode",
    url: "QRCode/{address}",
    defaults: new { controller = "QRCode", action = "Index" }
);
```

now call the api with such an url:

```
http://<server>/QRCode/address1?amount=33.33
```